# How to add icon in the Taskbar when we are using Python Tkinter Framework?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I add icon in the taskbar when I am using Python Tkinter Framework.

[image]

I was trying to get the icon symbol that is visible in the pop-up window in the taskbar. I have tried but I didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by compiling this to an executable file with **pyinstaller**.
Make sure to pass in `--icon=path/to/icon` while building.

## Example

```bash
pyinstaller --icon=sample.ico test.py
```